# cast custom content to the chromecast

Tags: java, android, chromecast

(Apologies for the an abstract question)

I am trying to develop a simple android application with chromecast library. The android application streams custom content.  The custom content can be List or List.

I looked into few examples online , one that I followed : https://www.binpress.com/tutorial/building-an-android-google-cast-sender-app/161
I noticed here the content that you want to cast is created via:  MediaInfo.Builder and it takes String as a parameter which is URL of the video . ( although documentation says it is a content id actually).

I am not finding the correct direction what needs to be looked for to be able to cast a List to the screen.

EDIT: 
Is it possible to cast your application to the chromecast

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to take a look at [Remote Display](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/remote) APIs in the Cast SDK; that allows you to render a view, from your application, in your chromecast; the content of that view is up to you. The MediaInfo is tailored toward playback of media (video/audio) content.